# Setting locale in MAT_DATE_LOCALE dynamically for Angular Material Datepickers

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have this providers array in app.module.ts

```
providers: [DashboardService,       
    {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: loadLocale,
        deps: [HttpClient],
        multi: true,
    },
    {
        provide: MAT_DATE_LOCALE,            
        useValue: "en-GB"
    }        
],
bootstrap: [AppComponent]
```

I am loading the locale from a web api using APP_INITIALIZER provider with a function loadLocale and I have confirmed that hits the backend and returns the locale.

The tricky part is to then set that locale value in the MAT_DATE_LOCALE provider so that "en-GB" is replaced with whatever was set in APP_INITIALIZER so my Angular Material DatePickers then pick it up.

APP_INITIALIZER is calling loadLocale() at the bottom of app.module.ts to get the locale from the api

```
export function loadLocale(http: HttpClient) {    

return () => {
    return http.get('api/dashboard/profile')
        .toPromise()
        .then((data: any) => {
            
            let profile = data as IProfile;            
            let locale = profile.locale;
            return profile.locale;

        })
        .catch((error: any) => {
            console.error('Failed to load user locale', error);
        });
};
```

}